# How to use Inno Setup scripting to append to a text file?

Tags: append, text-files, inno-setup, pascalscript

How can I append text to a file?

Comment: Related: [Using Inno Setup scripting to insert lines into a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73711995/850848)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`SaveStringToFile()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_savestringtofile.htm) function to append text to a file.

Answer (score 4):

```pascal
fileName := ExpandConstant('{pf}\{#MyAppName}\batch.bat');
SetArrayLength(lines, 3);
lines[0] := 'echo hello';
lines[1] := 'pause';
lines[2] := 'exit';
Result := SaveStringsToFile(filename,lines,true);
```

Comment: Some commentary would be helpful.

Comment: `{pf}\{#MyAppName}` should be `{app}`.