# Using Inno Setup scripting to insert lines into a text file?

Tags: text-files, inno-setup, pascalscript

Objective is to insert multiple lines (once) at beginning of text document.

But I have been having problems with the approaches I found. I've attempted to adjust them but it incorporates side-effect issues.

Two problems:

1. Appends end of file instead of inserting into line locations.
2. In its present design, it appends the file 3 times.

In reference to the other scripts I found both lines incorporating `Result :=` resulted in unknown identifier.

References:

- [How to use Inno Setup scripting to append to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560900/how-to-use-inno-setup-scripting-to-edit-a-text-file)
- https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/477984/createplusandpluswriteplusbatchplusfileplusinplusi

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  FileName: string;
  lines : TArrayOfString;
begin
  fileName := ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\xy');
  fileName := AddBackslash(FileName) + 'zlt.net';
  SetArrayLength(lines, 6); 
  lines[0] := 'A';
  lines[1] := 'B';
  lines[2] := 'C';
  lines[3] := 'D';
  lines[4] := 'E';
  lines[5] := 'F';
  SaveStringsToFile(filename,lines,true);
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There's no way to insert lines into file. You have to recreate whole file.
2. `CurStepChanged` is triggered for every step of the installation. You will want to insert the lines in one of the steps only (likely `ssInstall` or `ssPostInstall`)

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Lines: TStringList;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    Lines := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName);

      Lines.Insert(0, 'A');
      Lines.Insert(1, 'B');
      Lines.Insert(2, 'C');
      Lines.Insert(3, 'D');
      Lines.Insert(4, 'E');
      Lines.Insert(5, 'F');

      Lines.SaveToFile(FileName);
    finally
      Lines.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The code loads whole file to memory. That can be a problem if the file is too large. But that should not be a problem for files smaller than tens of MBs. Also repeatedly calling `Insert` is not efficient. But for small files and few lines, this should not be a problem either.